# Use created DLL in a console app?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, dll

I have a DLL with the following code

```
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ApplicationCheck
{
    public  class ApCkr
    {

        #region .NET
        public string Netframeworkavailable()
        {
            bool NETinstall;
            RegistryKey k1 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v4\\Client");
            if (k1 == null)
            {
                NETinstall = false;
            }
            else
            {
                NETinstall = true;
            }
            return NETinstall.ToString();
        }


        #endregion

        #region PDF
        public string PDFavailable()
        {
            bool PDFinstall;
            RegistryKey k2 = Registry.ClassesRoot.OpenSubKey(".pdf");
            if (k2 == null)
            {
                PDFinstall = false;
            }
            else
            {
                PDFinstall = true;
            }
            return PDFinstall.ToString(); 
        }
        #endregion


        #region IExplore

        public string IEavailable()
        {

            bool IEversion;
            string  k3 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer").GetValue("Version").ToString();
            string z = k3.Substring(0, 1);
            int a = Int32.Parse(z);

             if (a < 8)
            {
                IEversion = false;
            }
            else
            {
                IEversion = true;
            }
            return IEversion.ToString();
        }
        #endregion


        #region IIS
        public string IISavailable()
        {
            bool IISinstall;
            RegistryKey k4 = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\InetStp");
            if (k4 == null)
            {
                IISinstall = false;
            }
            else
            {
                IISinstall = true;
            }
            return IISinstall.ToString();
        }


        #endregion

    }

}
```

I would like to use all the returned(i.e  `return IISinstall.ToString();`) values in a c# console app as `console.writeline(IISinstall);`

i am assuming everything i have done is to this point is totally wrong
If thst is the case how would i implement my dll in a console application.

A point to note is that my console app takes no input from the user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a reference to your DLL from your console app, then call it like any other reference.

```
var foo = new ApplicationCheck.ApCkr();
Console.WriteLine(foo.Netframeworkavailable());
```

Comment: That can't be a snippet. In visual studio, add a reference to your from your console app to you dll, >> check for references in your solution explorer, right click and hit add.

Comment: I have done that.But i am having a hard time displaying the results of the dll operation on my console program.

Comment: @dylanSmith sorry to bother you too much But now i am gettimg this error.Do i need to change my DLL code?----  'ApplicationCheck.ApCkr' does not contain a definition for 'NetframeworkAvailable' and no extension method 'NetframeworkAvailable' accepting a first argument of type 'ApplicationCheck.ApCkr' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Figured it out with input tod's answer.you're a lifesaver.Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Check your spelling, especially capitlization. (use intellisense) I see it spelled Netframeworkavailable one place and NetframeworkAvailable in another. Specifically your code says

```
Netframeworkavailable (with lowercase a)
```

and the error message you posted says you are calling it by looking for

```
NetframeworkAvailable (with the capital A)
```

In general I like to stick to strict Pascal casing to avoid this so I would have called it NetFrameworkAvailable, but that's just me.

BTW, if you type "netframewordkav" ctrl-space you should see your method and select it from the list. Intellisense doesn't care about case and selecting from the list will put in the correctly capitalized call. If the method doesn't show up in intellisense that's usually a good sign something is wrong.